# Which is the blog engine for my needs?

Tags: cms, blog, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am hosting two websites, which basically contain two filtered views to one blog-like data base. Both sites have their own domains and the files are hosted on the same machine (currently in two directory, but could be changed to one directory easily).

Now, as a matter of fact, I am sick of maintaining my own php code just for such a blog, so I thought, there must be a blog engine out there which I can use instead.

So I googled a bit and I simply don't know with which engine to start trying out.
Can you help me an tell me which engine is able to fullfil my requirements. I don't need a setup/configuration tutorial so something. I will figure that out myself as soon as I know which software to look at.

My Requirements:

- I want to continue to host the sites by myself.
- I want to use different design templates on both blogs.
- I want to feed both blogs from one data base and filter the entries, e.g. through tags, so I can have entries showing on only one site or on both sites.
- I want to write entries in two languages, so the user can see the whole site in the language he/she selects. However, I want these still to be one blog entries, i.e. if a user comments on an entry I want that comment to show in all versions (both languages and both sites if the entrie is visible on both sites).
- I want RSS-Feeds (or similar) of the pages (filtered, similar to the webpages themself).

Does anyone know a simple/small CMS which can do that for me without being too huge?

Comment: Your requirements aren't really simple/small, so it's hard to have an appropriate (simple/small) CMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with WordPress although you would probably have to write a plugin for the languages part. I don't think you'll find anything off-the-shelf that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks. So I will look into WordPress. If I can make it do what I want with one or two self-written plugins (if I have to) I would be happy.

Comment: There are plugins for doing multi-language content. I can't make a specific recommendation, but they do exist. At worst, you can just dupe each of your content fields and then pick which version to display based on the user's language selection.